# Filtrar un array de objetos y agrupar por fecha

Tags: javascript, json, filtro, group-by

Hay alguna función nativa de MySQL que me ayude a agrupar la información por días ,lo he intentado de varias maneras pero GROUP By solo me trae un resultado por día.

Esta es mi query :

```
const {room , year } = req.body;

SELECT * from Chat WHERE  room=" + mysql.connection.escape(room) + " AND YEAR(createdAt) = " + mysql.connection.escape(year) + " GROUP BY DAY(createdAt);
```

Desgraciadamente, no me sirve porque como ya he dicho , solo me trae un registro del chat por día.

La otra manera que se me ocurrió, es la de tratar mi array yo mismo, creando otro array,  filtrando el nuevo por fechas, y ir metiendo en el nuevo array , el resultado por fechas.

Este es mi array :

```
[
    {
        "id": 9577,
        "adminId": 24,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-08T09:04:51.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-08T07:04:49.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9578,
        "adminId": 24,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "dssa",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-08T09:04:55.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-08T07:04:53.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9579,
        "adminId": 24,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-08T09:05:01.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-08T07:04:59.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9580,
        "adminId": null,
        "clientId": 1330,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Cliente",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-08T09:05:04.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-08T07:05:02.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9692,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T09:52:28.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-19T07:52:27.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9693,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "que tal",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T09:52:30.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-19T07:52:30.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9694,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T11:02:42.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-19T09:02:42.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9695,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "que tal estas??",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T11:02:46.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-19T09:02:45.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9696,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "estas??",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T11:02:50.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-19T09:02:50.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9697,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-19T11:02:52.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-19T09:02:52.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9698,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-20T06:07:08.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-20T04:07:06.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9699,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "estas??",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-20T06:07:09.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-20T04:07:08.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9700,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "hola+",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-20T06:14:36.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-20T04:14:34.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9701,
        "adminId": null,
        "clientId": 1359,
        "msg": "Hola rocio,mi nombre es Eva, ¿En que puedo ayudarte?",
        "emisor": "Cliente",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-20T06:21:57.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-20T04:21:55.000Z",
        "day": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9702,
        "adminId": 23,
        "clientId": null,
        "msg": "Hola rocio,mi nombre es Eva, ¿En que puedo ayudarte",
        "emisor": "Admin",
        "room": "Nirmine669217903",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-20T06:46:56.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-20T04:46:55.000Z",
        "day": null
    }
]
```

Alguien tiene otra forma de hacerlo ??'

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido lograr algo parecido a lo que necesito, con este código.

```
  let nuevoObjeto = {};

            datos.forEach(elemento => {
                let fecha = new Date(elemento.createdAt).toLocaleDateString();
                console.log(fecha)
                if (!nuevoObjeto.hasOwnProperty(fecha)) {
                    nuevoObjeto[fecha] = {
                        arrayProvisional: []
                    }
                }
                nuevoObjeto[fecha].arrayProvisional.push({
                    adminId: elemento.adminId,
                    clientId: elemento.clientId,
                    emisor: elemento.emisor,
                    id: elemento.id,
                    msg: elemento.msg,
                    room: elemento.room,
                    createdAt: elemento.createdAt,
                });

            });
            console.log(nuevoObjeto, "Consoleando datos del nuevoObjeto");
```

Si exite otra forma mejor que seguro que si, por favor compartirla..

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, corrige tanto tu pregunta como tu respuesta. En la pregunta, ¿a qué lenguaje estás haciendo referencia? ("array" y "objeto" no son etiquetas descriptivas: elimínalas y agrega etiquetas _relevantes_); además, formatea el código. En la respuesta: ¿qué hace este código? Recuerda que debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino también para los demás que tengan un problema similar al tuyo. Edita tu pregunta y respuesta en base a [answer], [ask], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.